# Not following an argument while proving continuity is enough for a function to be a branch of logarithm.

Tags: complex-analysis

The proposition is:  Suppose $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open and $f \in C(V)$ that satisfy $e^{f(z)}=z$ for every $z \in V$. Then $f \in H(V)$.
So first we showed that $f$ is injective. Then for holomorphicity it went like this. For every small nonzero $h$, $f(x+h)-f(z) \neq 0$. Therefore,
$$
\underset{h \to 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{h}{f(z+h)-f(z)}= \underset{h \to 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{z+h-z}{f(z+h)-f(z)} = \underset{h \to 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{e^{f(z+h)}-e^{f(z)}}{f(z+h)-f(z)}=e^{f(z)} = z
$$
I don't follow how 3rd equality. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: shouldn't you have $z  + h - z$ in the numerator of the second expression ?

Comment: It should be $V\subseteq \Bbb C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $\exp'(z)=\exp(z)$; in other words, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta^*>0$ such that$$|z_2-z_1|<\delta^*\implies\left|\frac{e^{z_2}-e^{z_1}}{z_2-z_1}-e^{z_1}\right|<\varepsilon.$$On the other hand, $f$ is continuous. So, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|h|<\delta\implies|f(z+h)-f(z)|<\delta^*.$$Therefore,$$|h|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{e^{f(z+h)}-e^{f(z)}}{f(z+h)-f(z)}-e^{f(z)}\right|<\varepsilon.$$Since there is such a $\delta$ for every $\varepsilon>0$,$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{f(z+h)}-e^{f(z)}}{f(z+h)-f(z)}=e^{f(z)}.$$